# G- pon router as media converter

Tags: router, fiber

I have a couple of g-pon routers like huwai eg8145v5 and ZTE router can I configure this router in bridge mode and use like media converter for transmitting cctv signal through fiber

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @davidgo.     What's downvoted ..???

Comment: when I saw your post it had a -1 rating - I upvoted it so it is now neutral again.

Comment: What research have you done regarding this? Have you tried doing anything yet? What sort of connection options do your CCTV devices offer? I'd guess the downvotes are due to the lack of detail. A correct solution will require that you share any relevant information you can think of regarding the devices you are trying to connect to his, and also we don't want to duplicate any research you've already done, so please share that with us. Use the EDIT button to make your question better.

Comment: What extra details you want ..?